# While Loop Ideas

Tags: linux, shell

```
n=0
while [ $n -le 10 ]
do
if sapcontrol -nr "$sid" -function GetSystemInstanceList | grep 'GREEN|YELLOW' 
else
echo "SAP System successfully stopped!"
break
fi  
done
```

If the state is Yellow and Green skip it, wait until it is gray and break the loop. After 3 minutes a error report should come, if it is not gray.

Any ideas how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Which shell (or other language) is this in? Is this working code -- have you even run it? What happens? Far as I can see, 4 problems. (a) if takes a then; (b) if/else does not like empty blocks; (c) It will run your iterations about 100 per second -- what do you expect to change in that time? You need a delay; (d) It will run forever, because you don't increment n anywhere.

Comment: How does the `GRAY` state get reported if you're only trying to match against `GREEN` or `YELLOW`? Examples of the relevant output from your `sapcontrol` would be useful to ensure that answers really will work in your situation; otherwise we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following script contains everything you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set defaults for used variables.
# variables could be set this way:
#   var=foo var2=bar ./loopscript.sh
max_runtime_sec=${max_runtime_sec:-180}
recheck_time_sec=${recheck_time_sec:-5}


while true; do
        # use pre-defined VAL or use default (output of sapcontrol)
        # debugging: set VAL as commandlin arg and comment out the next line
        VAL=$(sapcontrol -nr "$sid" -function GetSystemInstanceList | grep 'GREEN|YELLOW')
        # switch-case with case-ignore Value of last command
        case ${VAL,,} in
                *green*|*yellow*)
                        if [[ $SECONDS > $max_runtime_sec ]]; then
                                echo "Error: max runtime of $max_runtime_sec seconds hit."
                                echo "       Now breaking out of loop."
                                break
                        fi
                        # reduce system load and retry
                        sleep $recheck_time_sec
                        continue        # do next loop iteration
                        ;;
                *gray*)
                        echo "Info: found VAL $VAL"
                        echo "       Now breaking out of loop."
                        break
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo "Error: no valid VAL found. "
                        echo "       stopping script now."
                        exit 1
                        ;;
        esac
done
echo "SAP System successfully stopped!"
```

Output of tests with different values:

```
$ time max_runtime_sec=4 VAL=green ./loop.sh
Error: max runtime of 4 seconds hit at Tue Feb 18 16:46:13 CET 2020. Script start at Tue Feb 18 16:46:08 CET 2020
       Now breaking out of loop.
SAP System successfully stopped!

real    0m5,019s
user    0m0,013s
sys     0m0,004s

$ time max_runtime_sec=4 VAL=yellow ./loop.sh
Error: max runtime of 4 seconds hit at Tue Feb 18 16:46:25 CET 2020. Script start at Tue Feb 18 16:46:20 CET 2020
       Now breaking out of loop.
SAP System successfully stopped!

real    0m5,016s
user    0m0,012s
sys     0m0,004s

$ time max_runtime_sec=4 VAL=grey ./loop.sh
Info: found VAL grey
       Now breaking out of loop.
SAP System successfully stopped!

real    0m0,005s
user    0m0,005s
sys     0m0,001s

$ time max_runtime_sec=4 VAL=foo ./loop.sh
Error: no valid VAL found.
       stopping script now.

real    0m0,007s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,006s
```

Comment: Instead of calling out to date, you can use the builtin [`$SECONDS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS).

Comment: Otherwise, this is just about what I would write. This is a perfect place for `case`

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestions. I updated the script above.

Comment: `grep 'GREEN|YELLOW'` will only match with a literal `|`. I think the OP may have meant to use `grep -E`. Your `case` is checking for `grey` rather than `gray`. Still one unused instance of `date +%s`. Nice code though.

Comment: Oh. Probably need to include `GRAY` in the output filtering from `sapcontrol`.

Comment: Date removed, grey changed to gray. Thx

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you very much.